# SQL Server 2008 - Where Clause AND OR

Tags: sql-server-2008

(Read Only DB)I have the below Where Clause and it's slowing down my query. Is there a more efficeint way to write what I have below?
Also, how do I only pull back data only for 2016?  with using the OR statement?

```
WHERE 1=1
AND b.Year(b.CreateDate)  >= '2016'
AND B.ProcedureCode1 IN ('G0277','99183') 
OR B.ProcedureCode2 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode3 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode4 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode5 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode6 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode7 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode8 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode9 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode10 IN ('G0277','99183')
```

Comment: We know too little about your schema.

Comment: Can you get rid of ProcedureCodexx columns to many to many relationship with ProcedureCode join table?

Comment: can you try to put all OR clauses in ( ) for example "WHERE 1=1

AND
( 
B.ProcedureCode1 IN ('G0277','99183') 
OR B.ProcedureCode2 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode3 IN ('G0277','99183')
OR B.ProcedureCode4 IN ('G0277','99183')"...
)

Comment: I don't think it's more efficient but at least it's more readable: `'G0277' IN(B.ProcedureCode1, B.ProcedureCode2, ... B.ProcedureCode10) OR '99183' IN(B.ProcedureCode1, B.ProcedureCode2, ... B.ProcedureCode10)`

Comment: You could use UNPIVOT to have only one predicate, but this would probably not make the performance any better.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Is this possible to do? If so, how would this look. on the Where Clause?

Comment: @MrJohn yes, it's possible. it would look just Like I've written, only with more columns in each IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your schema to have many to many relationship with ProcedureCode table, you can try to create indexes on your ProcedureCodexx tables:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_B_ProcedureCode1
ON B (ProcedureCode1)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_B_ProcedureCode2
ON B (ProcedureCode1)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, a couple questions. I would add this where in my query? I have a Declare, Set,  IF and then a Select Statement. Also, the correct syntax would look like                                                                                         CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_B_ProcedureCode1
ON Dim_ServiceLines (99183)
GO

Comment: You should run this only once to create index on your columns to allow faster searching. Please see this for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp I also recommend to change your table definition to get rid of ProcedureCodexx pattern